# Creating a list of random emails - how to output a list?

Tags: javascript

I wrote some function the creates randoom email addrresses. 
The next thing is to put them in a combined list, along with a number aside each one. The list should be 10 items long. 
All I managed to get so far is a list that generates the same email * the length. How should I do it?
This is the code so far :

```js
function createRan(limit) {
  var result = document.querySelector('#test');
  var genEmail = ''
  var num = 0
  var suffix = '@gmail.com'
  var suffix2 = '@hotmail.com'
  var counter = Math.round(getRandomInt(0, 1))
  var address = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 8);

  while (num <= limit) {
    if (counter === 0) {
      genEmail = address + suffix
      num++
      result.innerHTML += `${num} ${genEmail} <br></br>`
    } else if (counter === 1) {
      genEmail = address + suffix2
      num++
      result.innerHTML += `${num} ${genEmail} <br></br>`

    }
  }
}

createRan(10)

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

```html
<pre id="test"></pre>
```

Comment: For starters, you'll need to move the code for creating the random email address `var address = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 8);` to inside the loop, so that it generates a _new_ random email every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function createRan(limit) {
  var result = document.querySelector('#test');
  var genEmail = ''
  var num = 0
  var suffix = '@gmail.com'
  var suffix2 = '@hotmail.com'

  while (num < limit) {
    let counter = Math.round(getRandomInt(0, 1))
    let address = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 8);
    if (counter === 0) {
      genEmail = address + suffix
      num++
      result.innerHTML += `${num} ${genEmail} <br></br>`
    } else if (counter === 1) {
      genEmail = address + suffix2
      num++
      result.innerHTML += `${num} ${genEmail} <br></br>`

    }
  }
}

createRan(10)

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

```html
<pre id="test"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to redefine `counter` and `address` variables in your loop (as [@ajxs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5931673/ajxs) wrote):

```js
function createRan(limit) {
var result = document.getElementById("test");
var genEmail = ''
var num = 0
var suffix = '@gmail.com'
var suffix2 = '@hotmail.com'
var counter
var address

while (num++ <= limit) {
    counter = Math.round(getRandomInt(0, 1))
    address = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 8);
    if (counter === 0) {
        genEmail = address + suffix
    } else if (counter === 1) {
        genEmail = address + suffix2
    }
    result.innerHTML += `${num} ${genEmail} <br></br>` 
  }
}
createRan(10)

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

```html
<pre id="test"></pre>
```

Comment: Thank u all guys ! Appreciated

Comment: @YossiDagan You can upvote good answers and mark an answer as accepted, to help others find the good answers. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the address in to the loop. you should create a new address in each iteration.

```
function createRan(limit) {

    var result = document.querySelector('#test');
    var genEmail = '';
    var num = 0;
    var suffix = '@gmail.com';
    var suffix2 = '@hotmail.com';
    var counter;
    var address;

    while (num <= limit) {
        counter = Math.round(getRandomInt(0, 1));
        address = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 8);

        if (counter === 0) {
            genEmail = address + suffix;
            num++;
            result.innerHTML += `${num} ${genEmail} <br></br>`;
        } else if (counter === 1) {
            genEmail = address + suffix2;
            num++;
            result.innerHTML += `${num} ${genEmail} <br></br>`;

        }
    }
}

createRan(10);

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generating the same email because your address variable is outside of the loop, so it only gets declared once. You could also simplify your code by using a for loop instead of a while loop.

```js
function createRan(limit) {

  var result = document.querySelector('#test');
  var genEmail = ''
  var suffix = '@gmail.com'
  var suffix2 = '@hotmail.com'

  for (let i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
    var address = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 8);
    var counter = Math.round(getRandomInt(0, 1));
    if (counter === 0) {
     genEmail = address + suffix;
    } else if (counter === 1) {
     genEmail = address + suffix2;
    }
    result.innerHTML += `${i} ${genEmail} <br></br>`
  }
}

createRan(10)

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

```html
<pre id="test"></pre>
```